# How do I send an ICU UnicodeString using a boost::asio:write call?

Tags: c++, boost, unicode, boost-asio, icu

I'm currently using the ICU library to handle Unicode data, and am trying to send a `UnicodeString` over a socket. Currently looking at the example using a basic time server:

[Daytime.3 - An asynchronous TCP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html)

```
boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
    boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
);
```

Now, I've looked over various function signatures and it looks as though `boost::asio::buffer` can take a `boost::asio::const_buffer`, but I'm not sure on how the conversion to it works given a `UnicodeString`. How should I go about converting to `const_buffer`, or is there another way I should be going about doing this? Thank you ahead of time for all responses.

Comment: What encoding do you want to send the data in? UTF-8? UTF-32?

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks for the reply, I'd like to send the data in UTF-32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to send the data using `UnicodeString`'s default internal encoding (instead of forcing e.g. UTF-8 or UTF-32), then the following should work:

```
// given UnicodeString ustr
boost::asio::const_buffer(ustr.getBuffer(), ustr.length() * sizeof(UChar));
```

See [UnicodeString::getBuffer()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classUnicodeString.html#a34eda92a2c60797052116eb7acada1dc) and [UnicodeString::length()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classUnicodeString.html#ac4cf80391a0e523c27aacaba796aede6) for more information.

**EDIT** (in response to comment): To send normalized UTF-32 data, try something like this (adding error handling and extending object lifetime as necessary):

```
UErrorCode err = U_ZERO_ERROR;
int32_t const size = ustr.toUTF32(0, 0, err);
err = U_ZERO_ERROR;
std::vector<UChar32> databuf(size);
ustr.toUTF32(&databuf[0], size, err);
boost::asio::const_buffer(&databuf[0], databuf.size() * sizeof(UChar32));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is the answer I was looking for!